# MODX Articles: Can't retrieve article image with getResources

Tags: modx-revolution

I am running MODX Revo 2.3.2 with Articles and getResources. On my start page, I wan't to show the 4 most recent articles by calling getResources. However, it does not show the image. Tried to output it without `phpThumbof`, but it does not work out at all.

```
[[getResources?
  &parents=`11`
  &tpl=`articleRowTpl`
  &includeTVs=`1`
  &processTVs=`1`
  &showHidden=`1`
  &limit=`4`
]]
```

My `articleRowTpl` looks like this:

```
<article class="blog-item blog-full-width">
    <div class="blog-thumbnail">
        <img alt="" src="[[+tv.articleImage:phpthumbof=`w=750&h=200&zc=1`]]">
    </div>
    <div class="blog-full-width-date">
        <p class="day">[[+publishedon:strtotime:date=`%d`]]</p><p class="monthyear">[[+publishedon:strtotime:date=`%b %Y`]]</p>
    </div>
    <div class="blog-content">
        <h4 class="blog-title"><a href="[[~[[+id]]]]">[[+pagetitle]]</a></h4>

       <p>[[+introtext:default=`[[+content:ellipsis=`400`]]`]]</p>
        <a href="[[~[[+id]]]]" class="btn btn-default btn-mini btn-rounded">Mehr lesen...</a>
    </div>
</article>
```

There are no errors, it just does not output the image path. I double checked the placeholder and the prefix, which defaults to `tv.` as the documentation says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, found it. I just removed the TV-Prefix of getResources with

```
tvPrefix=``
```

and now I can access the TV with `[[+articleImage]]`.